# NotifyPropertyChanged not firing event [PostSharp]

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm new to PostSharp (just got my license) and I've been trying to use it in my app. I have a settings class a following:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Consts
{
    public string test2 {get; set;} = "foobar";

    public string test
    {
        get { return GetValue("test"); }
        set { UpdateSetting(nameof(test), value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); }
    }

    [Pure]
    public static string GetValue(string s) => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[nameof(s)];

    [Pure]
    private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        cfg.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        cfg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
}
```

Then on my subscriber class:

```
var cst = new Consts();
Post.Cast<Consts, INotifyPropertyChanged>(cst).PropertyChanged +=
                (o, args) => Debug.Write("PropertyChanged fired");
cst.test = "test test"; // Gives no result
cst.test2 = "test test"; // Event firing correctly
```

The event doesn't fire when I use methods in my getters & setters, although marked pure, but works fine when it's a simple property.

I spent the last day scouring Google for answers, without luck; no thread solves my problem.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect detects changes to fields of the class and then fires appropriate events based on detected dependencies (property value depending on that specific field).

In your case this is exactly what `test2` property does and why aspect works on that property.

On the other hand `test` property cannot work automatically. The value of the property depends on `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item`. First problem is that `AppSettings` is a static property, i.e. it is not possible to detect changes to it. If assumed that it never changes, then second problem is that `NameValueCollection` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which means that there is no way of knowing that the value actually changed.

You are not getting any warnings because you have marked both methods as `Pure` which they are not in usual sense of the word. `GetValue` uses global mutable state. `SetValue` changes the global mutable state.

Since there is no way to hook to `AppSettings` in order to receive changes to the collection, you need to raise changed notification when the property is set. This can be done by calling [`NotifyPropertyChangedServices.SignalPropertyChanged`](http://doc.postsharp.net/m_postsharp_patterns_model_notifypropertychangedservices_signalpropertychanged_918c7bd7) method. Your code would then look like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Consts
{
    public string test2 { get; set; } = "foobar";

    public string test
    {
        get { return GetValue("test"); }
        set { UpdateSetting(nameof(test), value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); }
    }

    [SafeForDependencyAnalysis]
    public string GetValue(string s) => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[nameof(s)];

    private void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        cfg.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        cfg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        NotifyPropertyChangedServices.SignalPropertyChanged(this, key);
    }
}
```

Note that if multiple instance of `Consts` class exist, they will not share changes there is no way to pass that information through `ConfigurationManaged`.

Comment: I don't know who you are, but I will find you, and give you a medal.